# Autocompletar formulario ingresando un valor en Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, autocompletar

Estoy practicando con **Vue.js** y llegué al punto donde necesito autocompletar un pequeño formulario. Cuando ingrese el código de un producto, el formulario debe autocompletarse con los datos del producto (**nombreProducto**) que pertenece el código.

El pequeño formulario:

```
<input type="search" v-model="registro.datosArticulo" placeholder="Ingrese código del producto"> //Aquí ingresa el código del producto (id_producto)
<label>Nombre de producto: </label> //Aquí debe mostrarse (autocompletar) el nombre del producto
```

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
productos: { id_producto, nombreProducto}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

En la problematica que estas teniendo, sería necesario un watcher que haga la busqueda correspondiente cuando realices cada modificación.

```
watch: {
datosArticulo: function(val, oldVal){
  for(let i=0; i<this.registro.length; i++){
    if(this.registro[i].datosArticulo==val){
      this.nombreArticulo = this.registro[i].nombreArticulo
    }
  }
}
```

},

Para esto me estoy apoyando en un registro adicional. Te dejo el codigo completo en este link: https://codepen.io/mabmab159/pen/wvrwMbq

Comment: El v-model dirige a una función que registra el ingreso del producto. Lo que deseo es mostrar automáticamente el nombre del producto,  en una etiqueta o párrafo, al ingresar el código del producto. Luego más abajo hay más inputs y un botón para registrar, pero se rellenan manualmente, en eso no hay tanta ciencia. Por eso solo mostré la pequeña parte del formulario donde no puedo avanzar. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @Michael, habia entendido mal el requerimiento. Corregí mi respuesta y tambien te facilite el codigo mas su funcionamiento a través de un Codepen.

Comment: Funciona bien, pero el v-model ya no dirige a la función inicial: registro.datosArticulo.